# Get ArrayList<NameValuePair> value by name

Tags: java, android

Is it a correct way to get `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` value by name ?

```
private String getValueByKey(ArrayList<NameValuePair> _list, String key) {
    for(NameValuePair nvPair : _list) {
        if(nvPair.getName().equals(key)) {
            return nvPair.getValue().toString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or, is there a shortcut to access `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` value by name ?

Comment: Wouldn't a HashMap be more useful here? Or is there some specific reason to use an ArrayList?

Comment: When you say "key", you mean "name" from the couple NameValue?

Comment: Yes, "name" is what I mean.

Comment: I don't know Android, but, this looks a lot like a `Map`, why don't you use one?

Comment: @Humungus i'm new to Android (&Java) development. How `HashMap` can help ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Answers popped up, I'd suggest either Jon Skeet's or AlexR's for an explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No - you're storing them as a list, which isn't designed to be accessed by "key" - it doesn't have any notion of a key.

It sounds like really you want something like a `Map<String, String>` - assuming you only need to store a single value for each key.

If you're stuck with the `ArrayList` (and I'd at least change the parameter type to `List`, if not `Iterable` given that that's all you need) then what you've got is fine.

Answer (score 9):

If you can use a `Map` instead, they work like this:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("key1","value1");
myMap.put("key2","value2");
myMap.put("key3","value3");

String str = myMap.get("key1");
//equivalent to your
String str = getValueByKey(myList,"key1");
```

With a `HashMap` the keys are not stored as a list, so this will be faster and you won't have to use a function to iterate the container.

You can then access all the values with `myMap.keySet()` and `myMap.values()`, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need other data structure. For example `Map<Name, Value>` or `Map<Name, NameValuePair>` if you want.

The first solution is probably more correct, the second is easier to implement if you already have code that uses the fact that pairs are stored in list. Map allows to get collection of values; `Collection` is a super interface of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

if your key or name is an integer, I suggest you to use a `SparseArray` instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Then you can use different functions to retrieve the values you want using the key, the value, or the index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` to `Map<String, String>`

Using Java 8 streams:

```
private String getValueByKey(ArrayList<NameValuePair> _list, String key) {
    return _list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue)).get(key);
}
```

But for code efficiency is better to collect the list into a map and work on that map. The function getValueByKey is not necessary:

```
Map<String, String> nvpMap = _list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));
String value = nvpMap.get(key);
```

Hope this helps!!!