# Any reason for URLEncodedUtils.parse return List< NameValuePair >

Tags: url-encoding, keyvaluepair

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse(java.net.URI,%20java.lang.String)

why not return Map< String, List< String > >

if it returns Map, user can easily query by key to get whatever they want.
otherwise user should iterator the whole list to find what they want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a **list**. If you read carefully the explanation, says:

> Returns a **list** of NameValuePairs as built from the URI's query portion. For example, a URI of http://example.org/path/to/file?a=1&b=2&c=3 would return a list of three NameValuePairs, one for a=1, one for b=2, and one for c=3.

That means that you cannot use a list to acces by value, because these type of data structures aren't designed for that. They doesn't have any "key" to use.

In this website, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) wrote a very clear answer about you cannot use a shortcut to acces a `List<NameValuePair>` value using a name or a key or for similar structures.

Here you can check the post: [Get ArrayList<NameValuePair> value by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939773/get-arraylistnamevaluepair-value-by-name)

Inside of the same post, you'll see different options to solve your problem. (Or could guide to you to find the solution)